# Basic "filtering" in digital communications

Tags: digital-communications

I am completely stuck on solving some problems for my digital communications class. Junior level undergrad class, so fairly basic. I have been searching around all day for related articles etc but can't seem to find any that are helpful. Any help would be much appreciated.
[Here are the three questions](http://prntscr.com/6njdcj)

For the coefficients my initial hunch is just to make `c2` and `c3 = 0`, which would leave

```
yhat[1] = y[1]
```

My other attempt is to create a system of equations so the x[2] terms are cancelled and the x[1] terms are the only ones left over, but this system proves difficult to me and I am left with a mess of noise. For some reason I can only get two equations with three unknowns.

```
c3= -3 * c2
c1 + 1/3 * c2 + 1/4* c3 = 1
```

where `c1,c2,c3` are constants

--OK so I think I solved question 1, I ended up getting c1=1,  c2= 1/3, c3 = 1/4 for part a

and  `((169/144)* SNR)/((4/13)*SNR + 1) = SINR` for part b.

Moving on to question 2, part a I got what I was attempting to do above, `c3 = -3 * c2`.

Unfortunately I am stuck again on part B because I fail to see how the coefficients would affect the `SINR` if we just want to solve for `X[1]`